# Browsing image gallery websites with two windows

Tags: browser, plugins, javascript

Imagine an arbitrary image gallery website (i.e. deviantart.com). You get an overview of thumbnails and upon clicking these, you're usually redirected to a dedicated page showing the enlarged version of a picture.

What I'd like to do is modify the behavior of the web page to open these detail pages in a dedicated window (which I then can move for side-by-side browsing). Any subsequent images I click in the first window (the gallery overview) should also open in the second window. (If those will be new tabs or just navigate the current one doesn't matter right now, just that the second window stays where it was before)

[image: example]

I realize this requires manual configuration for any given site, but I wonder how this could be accomplished. The pattern for the links which have to be modified could be easily accomplished using something like Greasemonkey with XPath or jQuery, but I don't know how to get all of them to open in the same window.

Answer (score 0):

See free applications [XnView](http://www.xnview.com/en/) and multi-platform XnViewMP

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's quite a cool piece of software, although I suppose it won't work on websites without downloading the images.